# Invalid Checksum for Freed Object in C Chess Program

Tags: c

I'm trying to teach myself C and am currently working on a bit-array based Chess emulator.

I'm not very far in though, and I'm getting this obnoxious error:

```
chess(59742,0x7fffa38903c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f9320c025e8: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

Basically here's what going on:

1) I `malloc` the board struct (which contains a bunch of `unsigned long`s) and then start to `play` the game in a loop.

2) In the `play` function, I call `get_move`. Get move does the following:

```
MOVE m;
m = (MOVE)(malloc(sizeof(MOVE)));
```

And this is where everything breaks.
MOVE, btw, is a struct as follows:

```
struct move 
{
    unsigned int from_sq;
    unsigned int to_sq;
}
typedef struct move *MOVE;
```

Most annoyingly, when I run the whole thing in GDB, everything works fine... running on my quite new OSX Sierra.

I've noticed a couple things:

1) When I don't `malloc` the board struct (`typedef struct board *BOARD`), and just call `get_move`, everything works fine (but there's no board).

2) When I `malloc` the move struct before I malloc the board struct (in `main`, for example), everything works fine until `get_move` tries to assign an `unsigned int` value to `move->from_sq`, at which point I get the error:

```
warning: No memory at 0x0000000000008000 (vs 0x0000000100000000+0x1000).  Nothing written
Cannot access memory at address 0x8000
```

Any ideas on why this is happening / how to fix it? I've looked around but not found anything quite on topic!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Most likely you are writing out of bounds of your allocated memory.

Comment: One problematic thing is that you allocate `sizeof(MOVE)` bytes, but that is the size of *the pointer* not the structure itself. That would be either `sizeof(struct move)`, or better yet `sizeof *m`.

Comment: My guess is that something elsewhere is writing to an invalid address and overwriting some of your other memory. Can you post the full source of the `get_move` function? Also, try option-clicking the "Run" button in Xcode, clicking the "Diagnostics" tab, and turning on the memory-related diagnostics; they might cause a crash to occur on the line that's causing the actual problem.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Oh d'oh, that's obviously it. Yeah, you're not allocating enough memory for your struct, so when you try to write to its members you scribble over random memory on the heap. NM.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/46623521/1848654.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have to admit to being kind of confused about your fix. It does work, but it seems inconsistent for the following reason:

When I malloc space for the board (`typedef struct board *BOARD`), I call it as `b = (BOARD)(malloc(sizeof(BOARD)))` and everything works fine. Actually, if I change it to `b = (BOARD)(malloc(sizeof(*b)))`, I get the same error I posted above.

But when I change the allocation of m from `m = (MOVE)(malloc(sizeof(MOVE)))` to `m = (MOVE)(malloc(sizeof(*m)))`, as you suggest, everything works. Why does it work in one case and not the other?

Comment: Want to add the the type of `MOVE` is also a pointer, as in `typedef struct move *MOVE`.

Comment: Maybe other things in your program are also broken. Hard to tell without seeing the code.

Comment: @IanHoffman You've probably got some other memory issue as well. `sizeof(BOARD)` is also incorrect code. You always need to allocate to the size of the struct, not the pointer (although oddly, your `move` struct looks like it'd actually be the same size as a pointer on 64-bit macOS, unless there's more to it than what's above). Something else is probably wrong in your code. Get rid of `sizeof(BOARD)` to avoid false positives from that, then try running with all the memory diagnostics turned on as I suggested earlier. Also, the more code you could show us, the better.

Comment: @IanHoffman I'd also scour through your code for any more structs you might be incorrectly sizing in `malloc`, because if there are any more, it could easily cause the behavior you're describing.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka, just did that and changed my `typedefs` to not use pointers. Now everything is consistent. 

My two structs are now:

    `struct move {
        unsigned into from_sq;
        unsigned into to_sq;
    };
    typedef struct move MOVE;`

And

    `struct board {
        // bunch of unsigned longs
    };
    typedef board BOARD;`

And they're then referenced as:

    `BOARD * b;
    b = malloc(sizeof(*b)));`

And everything works again.

Thanks!

Comment: Some random thoughts - hiding a pointer behind a typedef is confusing everyone (as we can see from the comments and the deleted answer), so a bad idea. Also, if you are serious about [chess programming](https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/) you will have to handle *millions* of moves per second and cannot afford to use `malloc` in doing that.

Comment: @BoPersson, I mean, this is mostly an exercise to teach myself more C. I guess I might refine at some point to eliminate all structs...

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions; (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned type is `void*` so can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.

Comment: We cannot do much more than 'guess' as to the root of the problem with the code.  For a complete/correct answer, please post a [mcve].